# Are web-page feedback questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

If I added a screenshot of a webpage or a link to it and asked if there is anything fundamentally wrong from a design perspective, would that be on topic? I know asking for generic feedback is probably not the best way b/c it would be too broad and may create more discussion than a concrete answer.

Answer (score 6):

Ideally, you should try to make the question useful for future visitors, as brainstorming questions get usually closed.

For example, if you are having issues with the menu, instead of asking: "What's wrong with my menu?" or "How can I improve this menu" you could ask something like "How can I make web menues easier to read?", "What colors are good for menu contrast?" or "Should a website's menu share colors with the rest of the site?".

If your example is still too specific (or too broad), you are more than welcome to link it in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner). For feedback I've also found [Forrst](http://forrst.com/posts) quite useful, but there are some other sites you could try. Hope it helps :)